# Get Range in Excel 2007

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel data coloring via OLEDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231608/excel-data-coloring-via-oledb)

Pls find the below coding

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + txtsheet.Text + "] WHERE [ASSET    NUM] = " + asset + "", con);
 OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
 int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

after this i need to get the range of the selected cells in excel

please help me for this with the coding

thanks in advance

Regards

Mahendran

Comment: You cannot do this with oledb. It just doesn't work like that. The answer is the same as the previous time you asked the exact same question.  EDIT - previous **two** times you asked the same question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it for getting range :-

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range SelectedRange = ExApp.Selection as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range;
```

Comment: Sir thanks for ur reply can u pls explain how to get the range of the selected cells via oledb thanks in advance

Comment: What you are looking for Exactly ....

Comment: May be this can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927822/selecting-the-excel-sheet-used-range-using-oledb-connection

Comment: sir i need to select the data from the excel using oledb then the selected data and the entire row should be highlighted with red color pls help me in this thanks in advance